# Can I use alternate proofs, with definitions, intead of the traditional ways given in books?

Tags: general-topology

For example, I started to study metric spaces and we have to prove that intersection of closed sets is closed. Can I use the definitions of limit points and neighbourhood to prove it logically?
I am getting back to maths after 12 years and self studying(for context) and I don't want to head in the wrong direction.

Comment: You can prove any statement you wish using any of the mathematical tools you have ever learned. Your goal is to convince yourself that statements are true, using only results that you also know to be true. Not sure if this answers your question. No crime is committed by you when you prove something via non-conventional means, although you'll get more out of exercises (typically) if you use only the methods that have been covered in the book up to this point.

Comment: Thanks. Kind of answers my question. I have to take exams so I wonder if my professors who'd evaluate me feel the same about the proofs.

Comment: If you are working within a particular book or course of lectures, the general rule (there can be exceptions at times) is that you should take care to use only facts that have already been established at that particular point. So the answer to your question depends on the order in which the propositions have been proved.

Comment: Actually, part of my notebooks look like literature, there's too much words than usual mathematical terminology.

Comment: Yeah, I take care of that. To not use results that are yet to be established till that point.

Comment: @Varun I was working under the assumption that you're self studying, since you said that in your post. If you're doing this for assessment, you should use only tools that you have learned in that class, or prerequisite classes.

Comment: Self studying but have taken admission in a distance education degree, so only interaction with the professor would be them evaluating the answersheets.

Comment: While I agree with the comment of @Alex, note that it can be tricky.  For instance, if you are given a Topology theorem on metric spaces, you might craft a proof that only applies to one specific metric space (that is perhaps commonly used) rather than a proof that will apply to any metric space.

Comment: @user2661923 hmm.. I get your point. I'll be careful about it. And now that I'm here, I've a community to guide me. Thanks.